# Firebase database how to get nodes on based of the child value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually i want to get online users only not the whole list of users.
This is my database structure:

```
Users
    - Uid
        - online : true
```

i want to get list of users which are online without needing to get each one of the user and then sorting it by checking the datasnapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Users` node is a direct child of the Firebase root, i recomand you using the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef
    .child("Users")
    .child("Uid")
    .orderByChild("online")
    .equalTo(true);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

**Edit1:** If you don't have the `uid` of each user, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();
            Query query = usersRef.child(uid).orderByChild("online").equalTo(true);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

**Edit2:** As you can see in the offical documentation, [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) adds a listener for a single change in the data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

When you write data and if you'd like to know when your data has been committed, you can add a [OnCompleteListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnCompleteListener) which is called when the Task completes. Both `setValue()` and `updateChildren()` methods take an optional completion listener that is called when the write has been committed to the database. This is an example:

```
yourRef.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
        System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Regarding synchronizing, there is a common way to detect when Firebase is done synchronizing the initial data on a given location. This approach makes use of one of the [Firebase event guarantees](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees):

> Value events are always triggered last and are guaranteed to contain updates from any other events which occurred before that snapshot was taken.

So if you have both a `ValueEventListener` and a `ChildEventListener` on a given location, the `ValueEventListener.onDataChange()` is guaranteed to be called after all the `onChildAdded()` calls have happened.

But one thing to keep in mind: **Firebase doesn't just load data**. It continuously synchronizes data from the server to all connected clients. As such, there is not really any moment where the data is completely retrieved. That's why you need to remove the listener as explained below.

Furthermore, note that you can remove the listener whenever you want. The best practice is to remove it accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity.

If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`.
If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.
If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.
But remember `onDestroy` is not always called.

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: but then also i need to get uid of each and every user first.

Comment: the reason why i am not using the `valueEventListener` or `childEventListener` is that they keep on running if anything changes in the node, they run again, which makes the device slow. and i also dont come to know when all the user's are fetched.

Comment: What you are saying is not correct. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: and can you help me by telling me how can i impliment onCompleteListener on valueEventListener, so that i can know if all the users have been fetched.

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Hope i was clear enough. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your items by specifying the child and value like this:

```
ref.orderByChild("online").equalTo(true);
```

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: but then also i need to get uid of each and every user first

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
ref.child('Uid')
```

.orderByChild('online')
   .equalTo(true);

or use

```
FirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child("Uid").orderByChild("online").equalTo(true);
```

Comment: but then also i need to get uid of each and every user first